# Why i can not open sqlite database in android BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,and want to open the database,in this code:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

                SQLiteDatabase db;
                db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,context.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
            //...
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

in this line:

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,myContext.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
```

i get this error:
[image]

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: where is `myContext` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `context` which is first parameter in `onReceive`  for calling `openOrCreateDatabase` method as:

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
                                       context.MODE_PRIVATE,  null);
```

> Why i can not open sqlite database in android BroadcastReceiver?

Because  broadcast life is very less so it's not possible to perform long running tasks in `onReceive` method like API calls, DB  operations or any other task which taking more time.

**Suggestion** : Instead of doing task inside   `onReceive` use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will do task for application and stop self when task  complete.